# Returning non-unique rows without group by in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have to dig though data in a few columns tables to find non-distinct rows based off the `Name` column and because each table has lots of columns (all over 50)

I don't want to use a group by because of the requirement to explicitly declare every single column.

Is there any way of finding non-distinct rows that allow using a `SELECT *`?

If it was just a single table I would be fin with typing out all the column names but right now I have 4 different tables to go through and see me having to go though many more to run the same process.

Comment: I only see dynamic SQL in your future, using sysbobjects and syscolumns.

Comment: I am not apposed to dynamic SQL, though I have never used it and would have no idea where to begin in crafting this.

Comment: In SSMS, If you drag the `Columns` folder from a particular table in `Object Explorer` into a query window, it inserts all of the column names for you, comma separated.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I was more thinking along the lines of using sysobjects and syscolumns to build a set of group by's dynamically that one just exec's .  You can then just apply to any table you seek.

Comment: @AnthonyHorne - I was just pointing out an alternative that the OP may not have been aware of. However, given it's a tip in tool usage rather than an actual solution to the question as asked, that's why I offered it as a comment for their consideration. It wasn't meant as a follow up to your tip about dynamic SQL.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever NP.  Just giving context in case I had not done so properly.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Thanks, I was unaware of this ability in SSMS.

Comment: And thanks to the but hurt guy who down voted me cause I down voted his bad answer then deleted his post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use window functions, in this case, `count(*)`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, count(*) over (partition by name) as NameCnt
      from table t
     ) t
where NameCnt > 1;
```

Comment: This will find rows where the name is duplicated, even if the rest of the row is different.

Comment: @podiluska . . . That is an odd complaint, given that the OP finds the answer useful.  If you read the question carefully, you'll probably figure out that "non-distinct rows" is probably intended to mean " non-distinct rows based off the Name column" (as it says in the first line).

Comment: @GordonLinoff The OP may find the answer useful, but I doubt anyone in the future who uses the term "distinct rows" correctly will.

Comment: @podiluska . . . Read the first line.  The question makes perfect sense in the context of what it is asking.  The OP is simply using a short-hand, which you obviously find confusing, but not everyone does.  (My reaction, as you might guess, is because you presumably downvoted my answer -- someone did about the time your comment appeared.  If you want to downvote the question, feel free.  I find the question to be clear enough.)